# What was a Rabbi Elector in Lithuania?

Tags: history, rabbis, tzibur-community

In doing genealogical research I found records for family members from Lithuania whose profession was listed as "**Rabbi Elector**".

What was this profession?

Was it a legitimate part of Judaism, or just "made up" to satisfy the authorities at the time?

Comment: This seems more appropriate for http://history.stackexchange.com/ or perhaps http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: What language were these records in?

Comment: @mevaqesh: I was seeing them in translation, so English.  Original must have been Lithuanian.  And I considered another StackExchange, yet this seems so relevant here....

Comment: It is perhaps borderline in topic. "Questions about the Hebrew language or about history or news of the Jewish people, Jewish individuals, or the State of Israel, except as related to Judaism, are off-topic."

Comment: Related: http://www.mindspring.com/~peggyf/pusalotas/html/rabbi_electors.html. I am getting the impression from some googling that this was a rabbis recognised by the government. He had to speak Russian, and / or have other characteristics.

Comment: The one point I _would_ make, is that legitimate =/= legitimate part of Judaism. 'legitimate' can mean, for example, qualified and carrying credentials, whereas part of Judaism, would seem to imply an inherent part. A legitimate rabbi may not occupy a role that is intrinsically part of Judaism, inasmuch as his role may be very different from that of historical rabbis. Nevertheless, unlike a sham puppet rabbi, he can be legitimate. We can wait for the OP's clarification...

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://groups.jewishgen.org/g/main/message/261616) message on JewishGen, a state rabbi was a requirement in Russia. To hold the position, candidates had to known Russian. The state rabbi or "Kazeny Ravin" in Russian had bureaucratic duties:

> "he had to register births, marriages and deaths, keep these
> vital registers and issue birth, death and marriage certificates."

Each town with a Jewish population had to elect a state rabbi. The people who participated in these elections were called Rabbi's Electors. These electors were comprised of the heads of the households in the town along with the board of directors of the local shul (see [here](http://rolnicks-of-lithuania.com/chap4.pdf), pg. 181, n. 195).

Note: If I'm not mistaken, Rabbi Prof. Shnayer Leiman [once said](https://www.yutorah.com/lectures/lecture.cfm/736269/dr-shnayer-leiman/golem-of-prague-fact-or-fiction/) that Rabbi Yudel Rosenberg, author of the famous (or infamous?) Nifla'ot Hamaharal (the main source for the myth of the Maharal's golem) had at some point in his life studied Russian so he could be elected as a state rabbi.

Comment: In Hungary there was a similar position: the "bookkeeper" rabbi, who managed the registers. Usually they got a decent allowance from the state, so it was a sought after position.

Comment: @Kazibácsi, well, you know what they say about Jews and money... :P